# Porting exotic repo structure from SVN to Git

Tags: git, svn, version-control, merge

I am in the process of moving and large and complex multi-module Maven project from SVN based version control to Git.

As way of background, the entire project used to live in one SVN repo. The project consists of a number of backend/daemon modules. A core front end module and then a number of client-specific front end implementations.

What we ended up with (over about 5 years, as these things tend to happen) was a very strange structure. Everything was in one SVN repo, but each module had it's own `trunk`, `tags` and `branches` folder and independent release cycles.

In porting to Git we made the decision to move the modules to their own, independent, Git repos. We used `git svn` so export each modules, with its `trunk`, `tags` and `branches` folders, into a Git repo - preserving the tags and branches.

So far so good.

Now I have encountered an issue that I do not know the best approach to.

What I have are a number of client-specific front end modules. These contains mainly templates and localisation files - for branding and the such.

How we did this on SVN was we have a `Trunk` module, which has `trunk`, `tags` and `branches`. When we need to brand our product for a client we then `svn cp` **two whole lot** into another folder, say `ClientA`.

So now we have

```
Trunk
    /trunk
    /tags
    /branches
ClientA
    /trunk
    /tags
    /branches
```

So, work continues independently on the two projects. Things are tagged and branched and merged independently.

**But** if a bug is found in the front end code, or a useful feature is added we merge `Trunk/trunk <-> ClientA/trunk`. Because the *entire project* is an `svn cp` SVN can handle this merge (almost) gracefully.

So how would I go about doing something analogous in Git?

I can see two broad approaches:

1) Keep the entire front end code under one Git repo, and have named branches for client specific projects. Use some naming convention for the branches and the tags. This would allow us to merge across branches.

The disadvantage of this is that it seems **really** hacky. A nightmare to maintain (oops, I merged my feature branch into the wrong client branch). And also very ugly.

2) Separate the projects into their own Git repos. This has the major advantage of being clean. The projects have different life cycles so they *should* be in different repos.

The disadvantage here is that merging across projects would presumably need to be done using patch files.

So, does anyone have experience of porting something similar to Git. What did you do? How do you maintain it? What problems have you encountered? Lessons learnt?

Do any of the Git gurus have a clever idea of how I could do this another way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The disadvantage here is that merging across projects would presumably need to be done using patch files.

Nope.  You've got exactly the right idea, administering separate efforts in separate repositories and merging them as needed.  This is exactly what "remotes" are for.

> we merge Trunk/trunk ↔ ClientA/trunk

Start condition: all the work's in the main Trunk repository, it's time to work on ClientA.  To do client work,

```
git clone u://r/l/Trunk -b trunk  ClientA # or /path/to/Trunk if your fs is shared
```

When work on Trunk's trunk branch needs to be merged into ClientA's trunk branch, in ClientA's repository you do:

```
git pull
```

on the trunk branch and you're done.

If you happen to have work that you don't want to disturb in your current worktree, clone off a lightweight temp repo, do the merge there and push it back.  You'll find all other needed communication among repositories is similarly direct.

Comment: I didn't think of this - still new to Git. So you suggest adding the `Trunk` as a remote to `ClientA` so I have some "origin" remote - which is where changes are pushed for CI and maybe a "trunk" remote from which I can pull to merge with `Trunk`. Clever. Is there a way to have that setup automated - i.e. remotes already present when `ClientA` is cloned by somebody else? We're planning to use Gitorious or Gitlab for a private centralised repo manager.

Comment: Clone as needed or convenient, that's exactly right. When you clone, the cloned repo gets the original as its `origin` remote, so that part's already done above, git's supplying defaults to the pull because this scenario is so common, the full spell is `git pull origin trunk`.

Comment: To supply default configs, use template directories and preload them with whatever you want.